# There is a PL/pgSQL free environment to develop for PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, ide, environment, plpgsql

I want to know if there is a free environment to develop in PL/pgSQL.

Writing the code in Notepad++, replacing the function and running it turns the process slow. I'm using pgAdmin(only to replace and run the procedure) at the moment, but this is not what I want.

I know that there is one similar question here, but this is not duplicated. All the tools to develop are paid, I want to know if there is one free.

Comment: Hmm? What exactly do you want? I recommend replacing Notepad with `vim`. It is pretty fast for developing PL/pgSQL.

Comment: What exactly is it that you are missing in pgAdmin?

Comment: Ok, I was using Notepad++. I only something that can provide me syntax high lighting, syntax completion and a fast way to test the procedures. The basic things from a IDE. I thing that is too slow developing in Notepad++, copying the code to pgAdmin, replacing the function and running it. I feel that is not the ideal and a environment for this can help, but I searched a lot and found almost nothing, only paid software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am very happy with following environment.

I use a programmer editor like geany or similar and I edit a file with functions - I put related functions to one file - this is similar to modules from other environments.

I don't use a copy to pgAdmin - it is terrible work - and I don't think so pgAdmin is good tool for editing and maintaining more functions - it is good for ad hoc changes. The editor is not strong - it is simply, and you can't use a usual tools like git, cvs, .. More - you cannot to organize a related functions to one entity.

If I have a one or two files, then I have a opened console, and just import a file to postgres via \i command. If I have a more larger and complex project I use a makefiles - so it automatically import only modified and depended files. This is very good and very effective when you have a project with more then one hundred functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a debugger, check http://pgfoundry.org/projects/edb-debugger/ that can be included in pgAdmin. I have never seen any other tool that can debug plpgsql, only pgAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar question and guys recommended me [Toad Extension for Eclipse](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-extension-for-eclipse/default.aspx). You can see the discussion here: [Development oriented PostgreSQL IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722197/development-oriented-postgresql-ide?noredirect=1)