# Development oriented PostgreSQL IDE

Tags: postgresql, ide

Could someone recommend PostgreSQL IDE oriented on developers, not on database architects or administrators. I.e. I look for an IDE that will increase my productivity in:

1. Writing stored functions (code completion and syntax highlighting)
2. Ctr+Click navigation between functions (or any other way)
3. Finding All References (where certain function or table is used)
4. Refactoring stored functions (renaming function or variable; extracting function etc.)
5. Refactoring tables (if I change column name, functions and views that uses that column should be also updated)
6. Structuring my functions during the development into kind of folders (let them be finally flatten on the database)

The project that I currently working on has hundreds of tables and more than thousand of functions. Currently I work with pgAdmin and my productivity is extremely low.
All database development tools that I checked so far from (http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools) do NOT cover even 10% of what I expect from a modern IDE.

Comment: Do you mean, like psql?  :-)   Well, now seriously, I understand and I feel your pain. Personally, in the interim I'd avoid pgadmin and instead focus on psql and a database text dump, using an editor with "find in files". But automatic refactoring and code completion would be really nice.

Comment: Have you tried [Toad Extension for Eclipse](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-extension-for-eclipse/default.aspx)? I'm asking because it's not on wiki.posgresql.org

Comment: @TomasGreif thank you for the link. I tried it just now. It is way better than everything what I saw before. It has some problems with navigation and I did not find any refactoring support, but anyway I am already happy :) I wonder why it is not in the postgresql wikipage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Toad plugin for Eclipse is going to be the closest thing you can find.  Unfortunately, having a totally comprehensive IDE with these features is going to be a huge project in part because PostgreSQL can use stored procedures in so many different languages, so syntax highlighting inside the stored procedure requires a vast amount of knowledge (in theory, to be considered complete, not only sql and plpgsql but also C, C++, Java, Python, Perl, TCL, R, Ruby, Lisp, various shells, PHP, Lolcode, and Brainfuck -- there are probably more but those are the ones that come to my mind).  Consequently the only hope of doing this is to tie into another IDE.

This being said I, and most devs I know, tend to use bash, vim, etc.   It is a fundamentally different paradigm but it is more flexible in many ways, and the limitations you do run up against force you to design, and test, your SQL in sane ways.